# Getting values of ul into variable which are not hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-lists, show-hide

I have this code:

```
<div>
    john<input type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById(this.value),this)" value="value1" checked="true">
    jhonny<input type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById(this.value),this)" value="value2" checked="true">
    jack<input type="checkbox" onchange="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById(this.value),this)" value="value3" checked="true">
</div>
<ul id="numeric">
    <li id="value1" data-value="info1">
        <div id="info1" contenteditable="true">john</div>
    </li>
    <li id="value2" data-value="info2">
        <div id="info2" contenteditable="true">jhonny</div>
    </li>
    <li id="value3" data-value="info3">
        <div id="info3" contenteditable="true">jack</div>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" id="send1" value="save" class="button" onclick="action()">
```

and this script:

```
function hideshow(e, ev) {
    if (ev.checked) {
        e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function action() {
    var values = $('#numeric li').map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('data-value');
    });
    $lis = $("#numeric li").length;
    var n = $lis;
    var a="";
    for ($i = 0; $i < n; $i = $i + 1) 
    {
        a = (a + (document.getElementById((values[$i])).innerHTML) +". ");
    }
    alert (a);
}
```

The Output is : [This](http://fiddle.jshell.net/dZ5ZC/)

Here the check boxes are linked to the list items in UL. Checking/unchecking them hides/shows the respective list item. another thing is that the list items are editable. In my code they are even draggable. when i click save the list items are concatenated and saved in a variable along with the changes made in them.

The only thing which is missing is when i hide a list item(i.e. uncheck it) it shoudnt get concatenated in the variable.

Ex: if i uncheck all the items then the variable should be empty. But here even if all are hidden the variable consists all the values.

I dont know how to do it. can anyone help me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not checking if the elements are visible in your `action()`. Try something like:

```
function action() {
    var a = '';

    $('#numeric li:visible').each(function(index) {
        a += $.trim($(this).text()) + '. ';
    });

    alert(a);
}
```

(I took the liberty of simplifying some of the surrounding code too.)

You can get rid of the `data-value` attributes now too, we're not using them anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below... it will help you...

Updated Fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/dZ5ZC/9/

```
        var id = values[$i]; // Get the ID 
        var element = document.getElementById(id); // Get the Element by ID
        if (element.offsetWidth !== 0 || element.offsetHeight !== 0)  //Check the element isVisible or Not
        a = (a + (document.getElementById((values[$i])).innerHTML) +". "); // Assignt he Value to Variable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selector like this `$('li:visible')` and will only select the visible LIs

PS:
Element IDs should always be unique `$("#numeric li")` this may cause a lot of problems in some browsers, if you want to group several elements, use class not id and select them like this `$(".numeric li:visible")`